# How Do I use the Logitech G600 mouse with my Macbook pro?

Tags: macos, mouse, games

How do I make all the buttons work, how do I configure different modes on this gaming mouse?

I've tried steermouse but that did no good for me? Any help with this will be awesome, I plan on using it for my mac's Guild wars 2.

P.S I run Mountain Lion 10.8.2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I stopped using the Logitech drivers with my Logitech mouse and installed USBOverdrive instead. It's a great USB driver that gives you total control over all the buttons on your mouse.

[USBOverdrive website](http://www.usboverdrive.com/)

Any button can be linked to all sorts of system functions, keys, scripts, etc.

Comment: +1. I'm also using USB Overdrive, with a Logitech MX310.  Works great.